# Ansible select elements that are blanks from a list

Tags: ansible

I need a variable with all the blank elements present in the *_names* list.
I tried this :

```
blanks: "{{ _names|select('search', '') | list }}"
```

But it dosent seem to work

here is the list:

```
    "_names":
    [
        "",
        "ABC",
        "",
        ""
    ]
```

To give some context, I need this variable to count the blank elements and compare it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy intuitive way is to `select` the elements equal to an empty string. An other one a bit counter intuitive but more compact to write is to simply `reject` elements (which by default will reject all non empty values). The following playbook demonstrate both solutions which give the same result.

*Note: the `reject` method here will only work as long as other non-empty elements in the list do not evaluate to false. If you ever false boolean values, they will be retained as well*

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
      _names:  ["","ABC","",""]
      blanks_select: "{{ _names | select('==', '') | list }}"
      blanks_reject: "{{ _names | reject | list }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - blanks_select
        - blanks_reject
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=blanks_select) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "blanks_select": [
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    "item": "blanks_select"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=blanks_reject) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "blanks_reject": [
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    "item": "blanks_reject"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: The *reject* variant works if there is no item in the list that evaluates to *False*. You can convert the items to strings first if you want to, e.g. ``blanks: "{{ _names|map('string')|reject|length }}"``.

Comment: @VladimirBotka absolutely correct, hence why I gave the two approach in case the current input example evolves. I added that precision in the answer though. Thanks.